# Tensorflow finding gradients of model output with respect to input on large batch size

Tags: python, tensorflow, gradient, tensorflow-xla

I am trying to use `@tf.function(jit_compile=True)` to create a *TF graph* as show below. I'm not able to provide a functioning code since it contains a lot of dependencies.

```py
@tf.function(jit_compile=True)
def myfunction(inputs, model):
  model = tf.keras.models.load_model()
  tf.while()    
    out2 = model(inputs)
    output = tf.gradients(out2,inputs)
  return output
```

Is it possible to include model.predict() in the above code so that I can use a large batch size. Model() call only allows me predict for a fixed batch size and I am looking for prediction on larger batches.

Comment: you probably need to provide more details, what's the termination condition for `tf.while()`, also why you want `.predict()` instead of `__call__()`?